# Where does "apportable load" put the uploadable ADK

Tags: android, apportable

I went into my xcode project folder directory in terminal, and typed `apportable load` in there, and it compiled my project, but I'm not sure where the ADK is for me to upload to Google Play... Does apportable create uploadable ADK's or, no? I thought it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Apportable build artifacts, including apk files are in the ~/.apportable/SDK/Build directory.

Full details about making release builds are in the [Apportable docs here](http://docs.apportable.com/publishing.html#publishing-to-android-stores).

Comment: Thanks. I can apparently reach this directory from the terminal, but how do I find ~/.apportable/SDK/Build within Finder?

Comment: From the Terminal, when you type open ~/.apportable/SDK, it will open the Finder there.

Comment: Thanks again. But now I'm receiving `-bash: open: command not found`?

Comment: Hmm. It should be /usr/bin/open.  Maybe /usr/bin isn't in your path?  Try /usr/bin/open ~/.apportable/SDK